# Android: How to create a customized edit text box like this?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to create to make this form in Android

[image]

1. You see the EditText has some shadows at the front. How do I create that?
2. I created AutoComplete Text Views for State and Place. But how to I add that line and arrow on it?

Comment: use drawable left and drawable right property to edittext.

Comment: Is it possible to use gradient inside EditText to create the effect? If so how do I set it?

Comment: create drawable with gradient and set it by using drawable left and drawable right property to edittext

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set background drawable to achieve.either create custom drawable with shape or use background images and put it in the layout xml 
android:background="@drawable/text_bg"

create an "testing_gradient.xml" file in /res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/grey">
    <shape
      android:shape="rectangle"
      android:thickness="10dp"></shape>
  </item>

  <item
    android:drawable="@color/white"
    android:left="50dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"></shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

apply the code in layout xml file

```
  <EditText
  android:background="@drawable/testing_gradient"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:text="User input"
  android:paddingLeft="60dp"
  android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

final result

[image]

Again, you can add more layer to input more images
[image]

Comment: Could you expand? Am not that well versed.

Comment: Is it possible to use Gradient inside EditText to set it up?

Comment: Yes, it is, create drawable file then input,<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:startColor="#FFC9F5FF" 
android:endColor="#FF008080" 
android:angle="45"/>
</shape>